# "Is this a joke?"

Tags: expressions

So, while learning the English language, I have seen some examples of this phrase but never really understood it; do people use this phrase right?

Examples:

- > *Is this a joke?*

  This one is right one I guess, I use it usually.
- A phrase that I have seen written or heard from someone:

  > *Is this is a joke?*

  For some reason I often see or hear "is" after the word "this".

  Should I consider "Is this is a joke" totally wrong?

Another question, why would someone use this phrase:

> *Is this some kind of joke?*

And not the usual:

> *Is this a joke?*

Does that depends on how absurd situation is, or alternatively, is it just simply people's preferences?

P.S. I heard all of those phrases only in my country, since I have never had experience to travel anywhere except my country.

Comment: My answer is rendered inaccurate by the OP's edit. I shall now have to edit my own answer.

Comment: "Is this a joke?" or "Is this some kind of a joke?" is often asked with a sense of irony, when a statement by the other party (or some other occurrence which both of you observe) is incredibly stupid.  It is a rhetorical question.  It might, eg, be asked of the entire 2016 US presidential election campaign.

Comment: Got it, haha. Good example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example (*Is this a joke?*) is a simple question that can correctly use the word *is* before *this*.

However, I think that your second example (Is this is [sic] a joke?) is "totally wrong". I wonder if you have made a typo, substituting the letter "s" for "f"? If this did happen then the second example should become, "If this is a joke..." This becomes a grammatical possibility if you then add a phrase to make a complete sentence such as, for example, "If this is a joke, *then why did you make a joke about it?*

Your final example (*Is this a joke?*) is a simple question, correctly written.

Comment: Yes, I did forget about "?" signs :P. Anyway, thank you for your answer. That's all I wanted to know.